# How to use button as a variable of clicked function in pyqt5?

Tags: python, variables, button, pyqt5, click

I'm working on some easy gui in pyqt5 and I'm a bit stuck on my clicked function. What I basicaly want it to do is, that buttons will change their colour when clicked in cycles of 3 (RGBRGB ...). My clicked function looks like this:

```
def clicked(self):

        if (self.button1.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"):
            self.button1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        elif (self.button1.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);"):
            self.button1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        elif (self.button1.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"):
            self.button1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
```

Which works well for one button, but I'd like to have one universal function that would take button_x as variable and do this colour change action. So something like (not working, just my idea what it should do):

```
def clicked(self, button_name):
    if (self.button_name.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"):
        self.button_name.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
    elif (self.button_name.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);"):
        self.button_name.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);")
    elif (self.button_name.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"):
        self.button_name.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
```

My working code is here:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 70, 71, 61))
        self.button1.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button1.setText("")
        self.button1.setObjectName("button1")
        self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked())


        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 70, 71, 61))
        self.button2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button2.setText("")
        self.button2.setObjectName("button2")
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 70, 71, 61))
        self.button3.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button3.setText("")
        self.button3.setObjectName("button3")
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 140, 71, 61))
        self.button4.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button4.setText("")
        self.button4.setObjectName("button4")
        self.button4.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 140, 71, 61))
        self.button5.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button5.setText("")
        self.button5.setObjectName("button5")
        self.button5.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 140, 71, 61))
        self.button6.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button6.setText("")
        self.button6.setObjectName("button6")
        self.button6.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 210, 71, 61))
        self.button7.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button7.setText("")
        self.button7.setObjectName("button7")
        self.button7.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 210, 71, 61))
        self.button8.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button8.setText("")
        self.button8.setObjectName("button8")
        self.button8.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 210, 71, 61))
        self.button9.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button9.setText("")
        self.button9.setObjectName("button9")
        self.button9.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.result1 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 70, 71, 61))
        self.result1.setObjectName("result1")
        self.result2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 70, 71, 61))
        self.result2.setObjectName("result2")
        self.result3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 70, 71, 61))
        self.result3.setObjectName("result3")
        self.result4 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 140, 71, 61))
        self.result4.setObjectName("result4")
        self.result5 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 140, 71, 61))
        self.result5.setObjectName("result5")
        self.result6 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 140, 71, 61))
        self.result6.setObjectName("result6")
        self.result7 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 210, 71, 61))
        self.result7.setObjectName("result7")
        self.result8 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 210, 71, 61))
        self.result8.setObjectName("result8")
        self.result9 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 210, 71, 61))
        self.result9.setObjectName("result9")
        self.button_exec = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_exec.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 310, 75, 23))
        self.button_exec.setObjectName("button_exec")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def clicked(self):

        if (self.button1.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"):
            self.button1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        elif (self.button1.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);"):
            self.button1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        elif (self.button1.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"):
            self.button1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks a lot for advices.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here: First, you have to drop the `self` in front of `self.button_name` in your general `clicked` method, e.g.

```
def clicked(self, button_name):
    if (button_name.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"):
        button_name.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
    elif:
        # and so on
```

Second, you can use `lambda` expressions for your button callbacks to pass the correct button to the method, e.g.

```
self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked(self.button1))
```

That way you pass the button you want to modify on click to the `clicked` method.

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER** use the python files generated by `pyuic` to create your programs. **NEVER**.
They must be used as imported modules, and your program should be created in a separate file. 
Read the documentation about using Designer to know more https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html .

> QObject *QObject::sender() const
>
> Returns a pointer to the object that sent the signal, if called in a slot activated by a signal; 
>   otherwise it returns nullptr. 
>   The pointer is valid only during the execution of the slot that calls this function 
>   from this object's thread context.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 70, 71, 61))
        self.button1.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button1.setText("")
        self.button1.setObjectName("button1")
#        self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked())


        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 70, 71, 61))
        self.button2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button2.setText("")
        self.button2.setObjectName("button2")
#        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 70, 71, 61))
        self.button3.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button3.setText("")
        self.button3.setObjectName("button3")
#        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 140, 71, 61))
        self.button4.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button4.setText("")
        self.button4.setObjectName("button4")
#        self.button4.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 140, 71, 61))
        self.button5.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button5.setText("")
        self.button5.setObjectName("button5")
#        self.button5.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 140, 71, 61))
        self.button6.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button6.setText("")
        self.button6.setObjectName("button6")
#        self.button6.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 210, 71, 61))
        self.button7.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button7.setText("")
        self.button7.setObjectName("button7")
#        self.button7.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 210, 71, 61))
        self.button8.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button8.setText("")
        self.button8.setObjectName("button8")
#        self.button8.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.button9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 210, 71, 61))
        self.button9.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.button9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.button9.setText("")
        self.button9.setObjectName("button9")
#        self.button9.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

        self.result1 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 70, 71, 61))
        self.result1.setObjectName("result1")
        self.result2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 70, 71, 61))
        self.result2.setObjectName("result2")
        self.result3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 70, 71, 61))
        self.result3.setObjectName("result3")
        self.result4 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 140, 71, 61))
        self.result4.setObjectName("result4")
        self.result5 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 140, 71, 61))
        self.result5.setObjectName("result5")
        self.result6 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 140, 71, 61))
        self.result6.setObjectName("result6")
        self.result7 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 210, 71, 61))
        self.result7.setObjectName("result7")
        self.result8 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 210, 71, 61))
        self.result8.setObjectName("result8")
        self.result9 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.result9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 210, 71, 61))
        self.result9.setObjectName("result9")
        self.button_exec = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_exec.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 310, 75, 23))
        self.button_exec.setObjectName("button_exec")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self) 

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.button4.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.button5.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.button6.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.button7.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.button8.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.button9.clicked.connect(self.clicked)


    def clicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        if (sender.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"):
            sender.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);")
        elif (sender.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);"):
            sender.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        elif (sender.styleSheet() == "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"):
            sender.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]